# Adding Assets to Custom Lightning Experience Navigation Menus

Tags: lightning-experience, asset

From the help docs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lex_gaps_limitations_nav_actions.htm) it states that...

> You can include these Salesforce objects in custom navigation menus:
>   Accounts, **Assets**, Campaigns, Cases, Contacts, Files, Dashboards,
>   Events, Knowledge Articles, Leads, Opportunities, Price Books,
>   Products, Reports, Tasks, Tenants, Work Orders, and your custom
>   objects. You can also add Home, the main Chatter feed, Groups, and
>   People.

However, I do not see a way to add the Assets to the Navigation Menu. [image: Nav Menu]

Is there something special I need to do in order to have Assets as an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heard back from Salesforce on the Success Community and it turns out to be a bug that will hopefully be fixed in the next release:

> this is actually a bug. The docs team has updated the release notes to
>   reflect this information -- "Assets aren't available in the Object
>   Manager, and can't be added to custom navigation lists. You can access
>   the assets object home from the App Launcher and individual asset
>   records from the object home, search, and related lists."
>
> They are working to fix the custom navigation lists issue for the
>   Summer 16 release so stay tuned!